# Importing QtCore from PySide6 fails with DLL-error on Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pyside6

I am using poetry for organizing my virtual environments in python (Running 3.9 on Win 10). When running python directly in the command prompt via `poetry run python`, I can execute the following lines:

```
import PySide6
PySide6.__version__
```

and get '6.3.2' as return.
In a jupyter notebook, executed by `poetry run jupyter notebook`, I get the following feedback instead:

```
module 'PySide6' has no attribute '__version__'
```

Moreover, importing `QtCore` by calling `from PySide6 import QtCore` works fine in the command line, but fails with `DLL load failed while importing QtCore: Module could not be found.` in Jupyter.
Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Comment: why are you trying to load QtCore in a jupyter notebook?

Comment: @Alexander: I am using the jupyter notebook for testing modules I wrote, which require Qt

Comment: jupyter notebooks don't play well with gui frameworks